# LINQ & IEnumerable<String> Re-evaluation

Tags: c#, linq

Good morning,

I wrote the following LINQ query

```
 public static Func<String, IEnumerable<String>> ListaCorreccoes = (StrPalavra) =>
    {

        return (from StrTmp in ListaPossiveisCorreccoes(StrPalavra)
                from StrTmp2 in ListaPossiveisCorreccoes(StrTmp)
                where PalavraConhecida(StrTmp2)
                select StrTmp2).Distinct();            

    };
```

which, to my surprise, is much faster than using two `foreach` cicles. After running this function using `ListaTmp = ListaCorreccoes("comutador");`, where `ListaTmp` is of type `IEnumerable<String>`, I need to print `ListaTmp`'s cardinality using

```
        Console.Write(">> Prima qualquer tecla para listar todas as " + ListaTmp.Count() + " correcções...");
```

and to print the contents of `ListaTmp`, using

```
foreach (String StrTmp in ListaTmp)
            Console.WriteLine(StrTmp);
```

However, both the last and prior-to-last lines of code cause ListaTmp and thus the query to be *re-evaluated*, which is so very strange since the variable is being assigned the result of the query. Why has this code such a strange behaviour?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because LINQ uses deferred execution. See [Charlie Calvert's article on LINQ and Deferred Execution](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2007/12/09/deferred-execution.aspx).

Try this instead:

```
var ListaTmp = ListaCorreccoes("comutador").ToList();
```

This enumerates once and stores the result in a `List<string>`.

You might find Jon Skeet's articles useful:

- [Iterators, iterator blocks and data pipelines](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter11/StreamingAndIterators.aspx)
- [Iterator block implementation details: auto-generated state machines](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter6/IteratorBlockImplementation.aspx)

Comment: The Charlie Calvert article has bitrotted. Here's an archive link: https://web.archive.org/web/20160214193352/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2007/12/09/deferred-execution.aspx

Answer (score 1):

This is because ListaTmp is not a result set, but a query. Specifically for the Count, you're actually creating a new query (you expend the Linq expression) which you then execute.

The real type of ListaTmp is not IEnumerable, but IQueryable, which is a Linq query.