# Lambda evaluations unexpectedly re-evaluating?

Tags: c#, lambda, collections

There must be something I'm not understanding about lambda evaluations and lambda inline property setting. I have the following code:

```
var zeroGroupings = ruleList.Rules.Where(r => r.DiagnosticGrouping == 0); // line 1
var oneGroupings = ruleList.Rules.Where(r => r.DiagnosticGrouping == 1); // line 2
var twoGroupings = ruleList.Rules.Where(r => r.DiagnosticGrouping == 2); // line 3

zeroGroupings.ForEach(r => r.DiagnosticGrouping = 1); // line 4
oneGroupings.ForEach(r => r.DiagnosticGrouping = 2); // line 5
twoGroupings.ForEach(r => r.DiagnosticGrouping = 3); // line 6
```

NOTES: `ruleList.Rules` is a collection (`IEnumerable`) of `Rule` objects. Keeping it simple and minimal, I don't think anyone needs to know much about `ruleList` nor about `ruleList.Rules`, other than the `Rule` object has a property named `DiagnosticGrouping`.

Take this scenario:

Suppose a `ruleList.Rules` comes in containing 2 Rule objects, and both have a DiagnosticGrouping of 0. Lines 1-4 execute as expected.

```
zeroGroupings has a count of 2. 
oneGroupings has a count of 0.
twoGroupings has a count of 0.
```

All as expected.

After line 4 executes, my 2 `Rule` objects both have a `DiagnosticGrouping` of 1, as expected. However, after line 5 executes, the 2 `Rule` objects suddenly have a `DiagnosticGrouping` of 2. WTH? After line 6 executes, both rule objects now have a `DiagnosticGrouping` of 3.

I was hoping that, in this scenario, lines 5 and 6 would not match anything, and would thus do nothing. It seems as though lines 2 and 3 somehow get re-evaluated down in lines 5 and 6, and thus match, and thus the property is set again. I don't understand this.

What do I need to do so that everything executes as expected?

Comment: It executes as expected ... `Where` extension return `IQueryable` you need to materialize it

Comment: That's the whole idea of lazy execution. Lazy evaluation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [LINQ & IEnumerable<String> Re-evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3976113/linq-ienumerablestring-re-evaluation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Where` is a deferred execution query. It doesn't evaluate immediately and populate a collection; rather, it executed *when it is itself iterated* - scanning the original source for matches. It does this every time it is iterated. There are reasons for this including composability and memory usage. In fact, not only can the source data change between query creation and iteration, but due to how "captured variables" work, the filter itself can change between this time!

Basically: if you want it to execute now into a list, add `.ToList()` after the `Where(...)`:

```cs
var zeroGroupings = ruleList.Rules.Where(r => r.DiagnosticGrouping == 0).ToList();
```